# Jlist Limit Maximum Number Selected Elements

Tags: java, swing

I have a jlist with an arbitrary number of elements.  I would like to limit users to selecting only 3 elements from the list.  So far, I haven't found any really convenient way of doing so, other than making a list selection listener and coding from there.

Is there any built in way, or best practice for in Swing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement your customized selection model. for example, like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);

    JList list = new JList(new Object[]{"111","111","111","111","111","111","111"});
    list.setSelectionModel(new MySelectionModel(list, 3));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static class MySelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel
{
    private JList list;
    private int maxCount;

    private MySelectionModel(JList list,int maxCount)
    {
        this.list = list;

        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
    {
        if (index1 - index0 >= maxCount)
        {
            index1 = index0 + maxCount - 1;
        }
        super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
    }

    @Override
    public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
    {
        int selectionLength = list.getSelectedIndices().length;
        if (selectionLength >= maxCount)
            return;

        if (index1 - index0 >= maxCount - selectionLength)
        {
            index1 = index0 + maxCount - 1 - selectionLength;
        }
        if (index1 < index0)
            return;
        super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when "SHIFT" key is pressed for multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html). and [DefaultListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html)

> This interface represents the current state of the selection for any of the components that display a list of values with stable indices. The selection is modeled as a set of intervals, each interval represents a contiguous range of selected list elements. The methods for modifying the set of selected intervals all take a pair of indices, index0 and index1, that represent a closed interval, i.e. the interval includes both index0 and index1.

You *could* subclass `DefaultListSelectionModel` and override the `addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)` and `setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)` methods.  Unfortunately, the [internals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.java) of `DefaultListSelectionModel` are marked as private, so you can't (easily, without reverting to reflection) access the bitset which represents the selected rows.  There doesn't appear to be a way to get the selection count, other than iterating through all the rows from `getMinSelectionIndex()` to `getMaxSelectionIndex()` and querying `isSelectedIndex()`.

Comment: chenyi1976 solves the problem of knowing which rows are selected by having the selection model retain a reference to the JList.  That works ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this but so far, I am just able to determine if it reaches the limit but still allows selection. Maybe someone could improve my code.

Here's what I did. I declared an integer array indices.

```
int indices[];
```

Then on [listselectionlistener](/questions/tagged/listselectionlistener), I stored the selected indices into the array then validates it against the max selection.

```
public class ListListener implements ListSelectionListener{
   public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
      indices = list.getSelectedIndices();
      if(indices.length > max){
         System.out.println("you can only select " + max + " items");
         /* place a code here that prevents further more selection or 
            still allows selection only to deselect the last selected item/element
         */
      }
   }
}
```