# Adding a limit to JList MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION

Tags: java, swing

I am programming a little java application but since my java skills are only 2 or 3 month old I am faced with some technical difficulties.

My problem is the following : A customer call a hotel and wants to rent a room. The employee (using the application) takes note of the customer name, phone and the dates where he will arrive and leave (that part is done). When the customer arrive to my hotel, the employee finds the reservation using the customer confirmation number. He now has an interface where he see's the available room for the selected class (economy, first class, etc.).

I want my employee to select X ammount of room, where X is the room ordered by the customer. I am using a JList to show the rooms number. The problem is I can only set the selection mode to a single or multiple lines :

```
myList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
myList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

I read all the javadoc and tried to find an existing method to set a limit to the MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, but in vain.

Any suggestion?

PS. My english is not the best. I'm trying to make this as clear as possible.

Comment: You'll have to create your own `ListSelectionModel` that has the capacity to actively reject or adjust selection based on your requirements

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917675/jlist-limit-maximum-number-selected-elements) example